# g++ "value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations"

Tags: debugging, optimization, g++

I'm getting some "value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations" problems, but I *am* compiling with debug enabled, as far as I know.

I.e. I'm using `-g -O0 -fno-inline` flags, so I'm not sure why is this still happening. Is it some flag I missed?

Compiler is `g++-mp-4.6 (GCC) 4.6.3`, OS is OSX 10.6 `Darwin Palace-of-the-Nine-Moons.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386`

Full compile options are `g++-mp-4.6 -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused -g -O0 -fno-inline -I/usr/local/include -I../allig -std=c++0x -c src/Toolbox.cpp -o o/Toolbox.o` for every file.

gdb session:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000021
[Switching to process 23874]
0x0000000100035d64 in al_get_bitmap_width ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000100035d64 in al_get_bitmap_width ()
#1  0x0000000100005e47 in Icon::resize (this=0x101244530, w=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>, h=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>) at ../allig/Icon.cpp:24
#2  0x0000000100005e1f in Icon::create_icon (this=0x101244530, _icon_size=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>) at ../allig/Icon.cpp:20
#3  0x000000010000ae24 in Icontainer::add_icon (this=0x101244210, tt=0x101244530) at ../allig/Icontainer.cpp:18
#4  0x0000000100002d58 in _al_mangled_main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff600) at src/mapedit.cpp:202
#5  0x000000010009ff17 in +[AllegroAppDelegate app_main:] ()
#6  0x00007fff82d45114 in __NSThread__main__ ()
#7  0x00007fff81f4afd6 in _pthread_start ()
#8  0x00007fff81f4ae89 in thread_start ()
(gdb) up
#1  0x0000000100005e47 in Icon::resize (this=0x101244530, w=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>, h=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>) at ../allig/Icon.cpp:24
24      ow=al_get_bitmap_width(icon);
Current language:  auto; currently c++
[...] 
(gdb) up
#2  0x0000000100005e1f in Icon::create_icon (this=0x101244530, _icon_size=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>) at ../allig/Icon.cpp:20
20      resize(_icon_size,_icon_size);
(gdb) print _icon_size
$2 = <value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>
(gdb) up
#3  0x000000010000ae24 in Icontainer::add_icon (this=0x101244210, tt=0x101244530) at ../allig/Icontainer.cpp:18
18      tt->create_icon(icon_size);
(gdb) print icon_size
$3 = 32 ' '
(gdb) quit
```

code snippets:

```
void Icon::resize (unsigned char w, unsigned char h) {
    unsigned short ow,oh;
    ow=al_get_bitmap_width(icon);
```

up

```
void Icon::create_icon (unsigned char _icon_size) {
    resize(_icon_size,_icon_size);
}
```

up

```
int Icontainer::add_icon (Icon *tt) {
    int ret=icons.size();
    tt->tool=TOOL_TILE;
    tt->create_icon(icon_size);
```

finally here the icon size was available.

Comment: Can you show the code this is occurring with?

Comment: @GManNickG I've added the debug session and some code snippets, if you need more code let me know, thanks!

Comment: (meanwhile I've fixed the bug I was searching for, but I encounter this problem very often, almost every time I use `gdb`)